# grails findAll findAllWhere inconsistencies

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm, grails-2.3

Given a Grails domain

```
class Person {
     String name
     int age
}
```

I can execute that  query

```
Person.findAll { age >= 25 }
```

But when I execute this query it doesn't do any filtering

```
def query = { age >= 25 }
Person.findAll query
```

I tried cloning, or nulling owner and delegate of that closure before passing it as an argument and still not luck

Also looking at the source of GormStaticApi in org/grails/datastore/gorm/ I should also be able to do the following

```
Person.findAllWhere ([age: 25], [max: 10, offset:5])
```

but it does work even though

```
Person.findAllWhere ([age: 25]) works
```

Anybody knows why that is. I am using `Grails 2.3.9`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation says:

> Note that you cannot pass a closure defined as a variable into the
>   where method unless it has been explicitly cast to a DetachedCriteria
>   instance

It should work if you explicitly cast it:

```
def query = { age >= 25 } as DetachedCriteria
Person.findAll query
```

Although it you wanted to create a reusable DetachedCriteria, it would be better to do:

```
def query = Person.where { age >= 25}
```

Then you can do things like:

```
query.list()
query.findAllBySomethingElse()
query.findAll { somethingelse == foo }
```

Comment: I'm accessing my DB through rest and was evaluating the different way of doing filtering   I ended up creating a builder to a criteria using a JSON map as the query parameters   something like { gt: [ 'age', 25 ] }   thx for pointing to the doc. I missed that line.